# CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM value cannot be retrieved from CMakeCache.txt

Tags: jenkins, cmake, jenkins-plugins

I have a project that I'm running through the Jenkins CI server and is being built using the Cmake plugin, and I am consistently getting the same error:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/580152/Celero/build/64
ERROR:Failed to get CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM value from C:\Users\580152\Celero\build\64\CMakeCache.txt
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and I can build and run the .sln file in Visual Studio using the files generated by the Cmake plugin. However, it never builds or finishes whenever I use the Cmake plugin. I've worked with Jenkins a bit in the previous weeks, but I'm still a noob when it comes to some of the plugins and settings, and the same goes to Cmake.

Is this a Jenkins plugin problem, a Cmake error, or am I just not setting something up right/missing the problem entirely?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

**Update:**
I have found that this error is caused by Cmakebuilder plugin, and was updated to fix this issue in version 2.1, and though I'm currently using that version of the plugin the error is still occurring. Could something have happened that my version was not updated properly (though it says that no updates are available) or is this an issue with the plugin that must be resolved?

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps my experience is old, but I have had trouble with the Jenkins cmake plugin. So I prefer to do my Jenkins cmake builds with a command shell batch script. This also makes the Jenkins build job more closely match my development build. I try to have my Jenkins build jobs be little more than

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../exports ..
cmake --build . --config Release --target test
cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, I made a batch script using cmake and that seems to be working fine. Hopefully the fix the plugin at some point, but this works for now. Thanks for the help!